# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri Equivalent in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have converted below ASP.Net MVC code to ASP.Net Core MVC, but I'm getting error like

> 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no accessible extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public class MMAPIController : ControllerBase
{
    public IConfiguration _config;
    public MMAPIController(IConfiguration iConfig)
    {            
        _config = iConfig;
    }

    public string AbsolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("%20", "");
    public void SuccessMessage(int personnelSK)
    {
       if (Logging)
       SmartLogger.Info(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss") + " Enter API- " + AbsolutePath + "  User Id- " + personnelSK);
    }
}
```

I have added this namespace `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftoto.png)

Answer (score -2):

If your code is in a controller, then it should inherit from ControllerBase so you can access the request directly as a protected property:

```
string absolutePath = Request....
```

If you are in another class you can access the HttpContext by injecting the IHttpContextAccessor into your constructor (as long as you are getting your class instance through DI):

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    ...
    // your code
    string absolutePath = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request....
}
```

But you will need to ensure this is registered at startup using:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: Actually code is in the controller, and it inherit from ControllerBase. Still I cannot access the request directly like that.

Comment: If I use second approach inside controller, I am getting this error `Error CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MMAPIController._httpContextAccessor'`

Comment: That code should be within a method or property

Comment: This did not work for me in a dotnetcore 6 controller

Comment: care to elaborate? This is how I access the HttpContext